# Why would server say it can't find .exe file when trying to execute .xbap file?

Tags: wpf, xbap

I created an .xbap application with Visual Studio C# Express.

Runs fine with F5.

Then pressed F6, copied the following files from /Release directory up to ASP.NET webserver:

- Motion2.exe
- Motion2.exe.manifest
- Motion2.pdb
- Motion2.xbap

But when I try to execute it in Firefox or IE: http://tanguay.de/xbap/Motion2/Motion2.xbap

I get the error:
Downloading http://tanguay.de/xbap/Motion2/Motion2.exe did not succeed.

This happens on two machines, both with .NET 3.5 installed.

How can I get my .xbap application to run on my hosting server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I then did Build/Publish to a location specifying that it would be run from a website, then changed the name Publish.htm to Default.htm, copies up the generated files:

- Application Files (folder)
- Default.htm
- Motion2.xbap

and now it runs: http://www.tanguay.de/xbap/Motion2 (in Firefox and IE, nice).